# Retrieve files from Vue in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, file-upload, vue.js

I uploaded files from my frontend using Vue to Laravel backend.

Uploaded using this snippet below:

```
addPost() {
axios.post('api/submitPropertyPhoto?token=' + this.token, this.postFormData)
 .then(r => {
 console.log(r)
})
.catch(e => {
console.log(e)
 }
},
uploadFieldChange(e) {
  for(let key in e.target.files) {
  this.postFormData.append('images[]', e.target.files[key])
   }
 }
```

When I want to request the file using normal Laravel request file helper method it returns nothing but when I use `dd($request->files)` it returns the details below.

```
FileBag {#68
  #parameters: array:1 [
  "images" => array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "name" => UploadedFile {#45
      -test: false
      -originalName: "error.JPG"
      -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
      -size: 21806
      -error: 0
      path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
      filename: "php639F.tmp"
      basename: "php639F.tmp"
      pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php639F.tmp"
      extension: "tmp"
      realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\php639F.tmp"
      aTime: 2018-05-17 04:26:29
      mTime: 2018-05-17 04:26:29
      cTime: 2018-05-17 04:26:29
      inode: 0
      size: 21806
      perms: 0100666
      owner: 0
      group: 0
      type: "file"
      writable: true
      readable: true
      executable: false
      file: true
      dir: false
      link: false
      linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\php639F.tmp"
     }
    ]
  ]
 ]
}
```

What I want to achieve basically is to save the file in the disc and the file name in the database.

Comment: You are sending the files via POST request. Can't you just chain to the POST request to save the files to the server?

Answer (score 1):

On your controller try these:

```
$urls = collect();
foreach ($request->images as $image) {
    $path = $image->store('images');
    // Store $path to your data base
    $urls->merge(Storage::url($path));
}
return response($urls);
```

Then on vue you can get urls:

```
addPost() {
    axios.post('api/submitPropertyPhoto?token=' + this.token,this.postFormData)
       .then(r => {
           console.log(r.data); // You should get a json of urls
       })
       .catch(e => {
           console.log(e)
       }
```

},